# Preserve Dir list in VBA

Tags: vba, scope, dir

How can I avoid resetting Dir?

```
d = Dir(root & "*", vbDirectory)
d = Dir(): d = Dir() ' skip . and ..
While d <> ""
    f = Dir(root & d & "\*.txt")
    While f <> ""
        ' do something with f
        f = Dir()
    Wend
    d = Dir()  ' RunTime Error "5": Invalid Procedure or Call to Argument
Wend
```

My understanding is when `Dir(root & d & "\*.txt")` is called, the first list generated by `Dir(root & "*", vbDirectory)` is reset.  How can I avoid this?  I tried placing the second loop in a function

```
d = Dir(root & "*", vbDirectory)
d = Dir(): d = Dir() ' skip . and ..
While d <> ""
    f = Dir(root & d & "\*.txt")
    call foo(root & d)
    d = Dir()  ' RunTime Error "5": Invalid Procedure or Call to Argument
Wend
```

hoping that the inner Dir call would be out of scope but it raises the same error.

Is there any way to safely loop with `Dir` without worrying that functions called in that loop might also call `Dir` and ruin the list?

**Note:**

I am aware of "Scripting.FileSystemObject" but would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: out of sheer curiosity - and I realise it is in no relation to your question - why the aversion to FileSystemObject? Pretty much anything in the last decade that can run VBA has the necessary library.

Comment: A) Distributing code among coworkers without having them manually link Scripting Runtime in Excel.  I know CreateObject can avoid it but avoiding it entirely seems better.  B) Performance is unreliable.  I have had code break if I call `.Name` on a folder or file object too often.  I suspect because it's probing for the name of the folder across the network instead of storing it locally.  I have had to cache `.SubFolders` like Tim said instead of using it inline with for each. I know its more robust but simple strings are more trustworthy.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a collection to cache results from your first Dir() loop: then run your second loop on each of those items:

```
Sub Traverse()

    Dim col As New Collection, fpath, f, d, root

    root = "C:\_stuff\test\"

    d = Dir(root, vbDirectory)
    Do While d <> ""
        If (GetAttr(root & d) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
            If d <> "." And d <> ".." Then col.Add root & d
        End If
        d = Dir()
    Loop

    For Each fpath In col
        f = Dir(fpath & "\*.txt")
        While f <> ""
            'do something with f
            f = Dir()
        Wend
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to wait before selecting this but I really hoped this wasn't the only solution, because it sounds like I should define my own subFolders function.

Comment: If you want to do that, then do that ;-)  All you need to do is break out that part of the code into a separate function.